# Exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/spec/ECPublicKeySpec

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">



    <bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />

        <property name="username" value="abc@gmail.com" />
        <property name="password" value="asasas" />


        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <!-- <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop> -->
                <prop key="mail.smtps.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">smtp.gmail.com</prop>

            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>




</beans>
```

above code is working fine on localhost but when we are deploying on server it gives an Exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/spec/ECPublicKeySpec

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `BouncyCastle Jar` is not found in class path , if it is working fine at local host then you must have used `Add External jar`Option of Eclipse which finds out the jar from your local file System ,

but when you deploy in Server you need to keep jar in `WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` directory

Comment: No I m not using any external jar file.I have deployed the war file on local server and External Server both but it is working fine on local server and external server is throwing an  Exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/jce/spec/ECPublicKeySpec

Comment: can you post your directory struicture and post StackTrace too